# System Settings doesn't Respond

Tags: settings, system

After installing Ubuntu, my system settings worked well until after I installed compiz config settings manager and then it stopped responding to mouse clicks. I uninstalled compiz config settings manager but the problem persisted.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I finally got it to work. I installed **Synaptic Package Manager**, and then I chose *Not Installed (reconfigure)* tab where you have packages that didn't installed properly.

Uninstall all the packages there and search for each of the packages in the error message. And Bingo, my cheese installed completely and finally started working.

I was also able to install ubuntu desktop and system settings worked perfectly using
`sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`

That did it.

Answer (score 1):

I assume by Ubuntu you mean Ubuntu with the default Unity Environment. I too had some problems with the system settings, but they can be done away with by reinstalling the **unity-control-center**.

```
sudo apt install unity-control-center
```

If it troubles despite the above command, I would suggest you to remove it first and then use it.

```
sudo apt remove unity-control-center && sudo apt install unity-control-center
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that if you are still having problems, one of the *dependencies of Compiz* could be causing the problem. A solution that may work is to type the following command in a terminal. However, if you are unable to access the terminal do the following:

1. Use the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.
2. Sign in using your name (the one that starts with a *lower-case letter*) and your password to begin using the terminal.
3. Anyway, type this: `sudo apt-get autoremove`.
4. You will be prompted for your password. Enter it. Then, follow the instructions to remove the packages.
5. Restart your system and post if that helped.

Comment: thanks so much for your answer. I did sudo apt-get autoremove and it removed compiz settings. I was still unable to get system settings to work and then I installed another one from software center but it doesn't look the same as the default installation system settings and it doesn't respond when i click on it from ubuntu settings. also when i try to install cheese, i get this error pasted below.he following packages have unmet dependencies:

cheese: Depends: cheese-common (= 3.10.2-0ubuntu2) but 3.12.0-1 is to be installed

Comment: If you need to install Cheese, the message you are getting just means that you need to install cheese-common in addition to the Cheese package because Cheese depends on it. Now, other than running sudo apt-get autoremove, did you remove anything from your computer before or after you installed Compiz Settings Manager?

Answer (score 0):

However, I am not a computer expert but if any of the previous options have not worked for you, you may have tried also the following. Since I had the same problem with either System Settings that didn't respond or I was not being able to change or restore the systems settings to previous configurations in four different installations, failures which each may have been caused by different software events or errors, therefore some were fixed following some of the steps suggested in http://itsfoss.com/reset-unity-compiz-settings-ubuntu-1404/  and others installations were only fixed after trying the following sequence;

Assuming the old GUI dialog is still available if you or any other person still want to use this:

Alternative (1) using ALT+F2 type

```
ccsm
```

This will launch CompizConfiguration Settings Manager

If the above does not responds then

Alternative (2) again, using ALT+F2 type

```
gnome-desktop-item-edit --create-new ~/Desktop
```

This will launch the old GUI Dialog and create a launcher on your Desktop:

Prerequisites to the above are:

gnome-desktop-item-edit is installed automatically if you have installed gnome-shell/gnome-fallback. It is also installed automatically if you have previously installed gnome-tweak-tool.

Alternatively, you can install the old gnome-panel without much of the bulk:

```
sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends gnome-panel
```

Alternative (3), if the old GUI dialog is not available if you still want to use this:

Using Ctl+ALT+T or if not available then Ctl+ALT+F2 type

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-panel
```

Then return to the Desktop GUI using Ctl+Alt+F7. On the desktop use your mouse right button, on the menu select "Create Launcher". On the Create Launcher image graphic description "Name": enter "Compiz",  in the "Command" box enter "ccsm" and enter OK.

On the Desktop click on the Compiz launcher to launch CompizConfiguration Settings Manager and enable the Ubuntu Unity Plugin.

All our four installations are running without any problems,. To complete the process, you may then type on a terminal `sudo apt-get update && apt-get upgrade` to bring all applications to par